# Passing querystring value into query1, then passing another value form query1 into query2

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a asp app that uses the query string value as a parameter to run  SQL query1. The results from that query will be used to run query2.

How I pass a value from the result of query1 into query2 in asp?

edit: The two tables are from different databases with different connection settings.

```
URL: www.website.com?ref=WO123
```

```
SQLQuery1: SELECT [valueA],[valueB] FROM TABLE1 WHERE [valueA] = WO123
```

```
SQLQuery2: SELECT [infoA],[infoB],[infoC] from TABLE2 WHERE [infoA] =  [valueB]
```

```
asp
PWiseGIS.SelectCommand = string.Format(sqldb, SQLQuery1);
```

```
asp
PWiseGIS.SelectCommand = string.Format(sqldb, SQLQuery2); with [valueB]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first SQL statement is excessive--you should be able to do this:

```
select infoA, infoB, infoC from table2 where infoA = (
    select valueB from table1 where valueA = W0123
)
```

assuming the inner select statement returns a single value

Comment: thanks, the issue is that the two tables are from two different databases with different connections. I've updated the initial query with more details if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `exists`:

```
SELECT t2.[infoA], t2.[infoB], t2.[infoC] 
FROM TABLE2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TABLE1 t1
              WHERE t1.[valueB] = t2.[infoA] AND
                    t1.valueA = 'W0123'
             );
```

This will work even when the query on `TABLE1` returns more than one row.

Comment: thanks, the issue is that the two tables are from two different databases with different connections. I've updated the initial query with more details if that helps